# Can I give bounty to myself?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I offered a 100 point bounty to my question here: [Exercise in Engelking's book regarding a disconnected space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585108/exercise-in-engelkings-book-regarding-a-disconnected-space) 
I solved the problem with a little help from a couple of the commenters, and wrote the solution in my original post. No answers were given. Doesn't seem right that the 100 points should just disappear...

Comment: More or less, when you put a bounty on something, you're paying reputation for exposure/incentivizing answers. Being able to give a bounty to yourself doesn't aid this purpose, but it does have potential for abuse. (This is especially true given that the commenters who helped you may have seen the question due to the bounty)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Meta Stack Exchange bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067):

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as **+0**, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.

Comment: so the points just disappear?

Comment: Unless another answer is posted to give the bounty to (or becomes eligible for automatic awarding), yes.